# Doctrine2 - query by example

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm quite new to doctrine 2. I want to do query by example - just like in Hibernate. Basically you give partially filled entitiy object as query parameter and ORM returns all matching objects. More here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-query-example-qbe

Is there any functionality like that? All I found to that point is ability to take entity containing id field as parameter, but what about other fields?

Comment: Do you mean query through an entity based on fields other than id?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can query through not just based on id.

If you need to get the doctrine object based on first_name & last_name, you can do something like this.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getRepository('ACMETestBundle:Person')->findBy(array('first_name' => 'david', 'last_name' => 'john'));
```

If you need to find one result based on same first name and last name, it will be something like this.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getRepository('ACMETestBundle:Person')->findOneBy(array('first_name' => 'david', 'last_name' => 'john'));
```

If you need to query through and get an array. You can use following option.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$contacts = $result->select('p')
            ->from('ACMETestBundle:Person', 'p')
            ->where('p.first_name = :fName')
            ->andWhere('p.last_name = :lName')
            ->setParameter('fname', 'david')
            ->setParameter('lname', 'john')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

So basically there are many ways/options that you could loop through a query by not just restricting to id.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers!